# Is it possible to label one commit as done by two people on github?

Tags: git, github, pair-programming

When I am paring with one of my team mates, we use one computer, either his or mine.
But we both want to keep our github streak going.

So, is it possible to label one commit as done by two people on github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple authors for one commit in git now. Check [Git should support multiple authors for a commit,](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=451880) a feature request on git.

Comment: However, you can, with the proper workflow, have both an author and a committer, and they do not have to be the same...

Comment: @twalberg : I don't thing OP want this author and commit, he/she wants dual authors for a commit.

Comment: I understand that... Using the separate author and commit would be a bit of a "workaround". The only other alternative is to record the additional meta-data in the commit message. Or maybe use `git notes`, but that's a bit hackish, too...